# Java: Trying to get my code to print on one line instead of five

Tags: java

My code below is working but I would like for the letters to be printed on one line instead of five. Does anyone have any recommendations on how to do that?

Code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Problem67 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Get input from user
        String code = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Enter your secrete message");

        //Printing even characters
        for(int i = 0; i < code.length(); i = i + 2){
            System.out.println(code.charAt(i));
        }

    }

}
```

Test Data: Hiejlzl3ow

Printed Results:

```
H
e
l
l
o
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use `print` instead of `println` (nb: the `ln` in `print` means "print line")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `print` instead of `println`. `print` method prints everything without adding a line feed.

replace this

```
        System.out.println(code.charAt(i));
```

with

```
        System.out.print(code.charAt(i));
```